# Turn on do not disturb for single app

Tags: macos, mojave, notifications, do-not-disturb

Is there a way to turn on do not disturb for a single app rather than all apps?

Specifically, I would like to mute notifications from Outlook for Mac for about an hour.

Is it possible to do this in OSX natively, or alternatively through a third-party app?

(I am running OS X Mojave, version 10.14.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - do not disturb is a system level function on macOS and iOS.

What you’d need to do is make an AppleScript or other tool to automate disabling notifications for that app and then possible hook that up to a timer app or trigger (or just remind yourself to toggle it with a keyboard shortcut when your other manual timer goes off).

So a third party app on macOS clearly could do this, it’s just not been written (or covered widely enough to be found) since [there’s no API to make that app easy to write.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210120/is-it-possible-to-turn-on-off-do-not-disturb-for-os-x-programmatically)